# LWJGL Textures On Object - Java

Tags: java, polygon, lwjgl

I'm having trouble drawing a texture on a Rectangle Polygon.

Here is my current code.

```
texture.bind();

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glColor3d(255, 255, 255);
        //Top
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord3f(1, 1, 1);
        //Bottom
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1+height, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1+height, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1+height, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1+height, z1+length);
        //Front
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1+height, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1+height, z1);
        //Back
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1+height, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1+height, z1+length);
        //Left side
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1+height, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1, y1+height, z1);
        //Right side
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1, z1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1+height, z1+length);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0); GL11.glVertex3f(x1+width, y1+height, z1);
        GL11.glEnd();
```

It just doesn't seem to draw except a thin like around the block. Does anyone  know how I would fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the texture has correct sizes? Or try to use glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());